# starting Tomcat from Eclipse gives problems

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I start Tomcat via  `startup.bat`   located in the `apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin` folder.
I then browse to   `localhost:8080/MyCalculator/CalculatorClient.html`

and everything works fine. The html page is displayed.
I execute  shutdown.bat  to stop Tomcat

Now, when I start Tomcat from within Eclipse and browse to the same URL

```
  localhost:8080/MyCalculator/CalculatorClient.html
```

then i get following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MyCalculator/CalculatorClient.html <br/>
type Status report <br/>
message /MyCalculator/CalculatorClient.html <br/>
description The requested resource is not available.
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: How have you configured Tomcat in Eclipse?

Comment: Hi.
I've used these steps:
http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html

Chris